# NG Serve command not working, just showing available commands

Tags: angular

I have Run NPM Install -g @Angular/cli
is install successfully.
changed 188 packages, and audited 189 packages in 1m

23 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities.

But after that when I run any command of "NG". It is just showing available command and my desired command is not working.

Comment: Could it be that you're trying to run something like "ng --serve"? Correct format should be "ng serve" without the "--"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've successfully installed the Angular CLI but you've not created an Angular application yet.

To do that you should:

1. Install the Angular CLI (which you've done)
2. Run `ng new your-app-name`
3. `cd your-app-name`
4. `ng serve`  And other Angular CLI commands will be available to you

Comment: If you're running valid commands outside the scope of a project you'd get: "The {{name}} command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found." instead of the list of available commands.

Comment: I have tried it, but the issue is when ever I write any command in NG is just results in providing Available command none of command is working!

Comment: Sharing the actual command output on your question would be helpful for the community to help you out. What does `ng --version` output?